# good/flexible software for visualizing a dynamic network simulation

Tags: network-programming, visualization, simulation, plot, simulink

I would like to make a simulation of a constrained system indexed by time. This involves a network of agents/nodes that interact based on some logic/relationships. I would like to place the nodes on a grid 2D or 3D does not matter. I would like to have edges drawn between them, and text beside them. I would like to give the logic for the tags on the nodes and give indication of the states. In the style of simjava:
[simjava](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/hase/simjava/)

But more based on mathematical simulations than software processes. Graphing tools would be useful etc.
Any good recommendations? There is good software for visualizing data sets. Matlab's Simulink has a lot of complexity on non-discretec events, and is not as cartoon-like which is good for testing principle rather than analytics. Unless I am wrong and Simulink 
provides this

EDIT: A similar question asks about dynamic graphs
[stack overflow relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464000/410975),
it is an issue that does not seems to have any concrete solution except for customized solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.  Not sure if I'm on the right track or not, but have you looked at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?  It'll render graphs (including auto-layout with various different algorithms).  There are bindings from various languages, e.g. [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) for python. If you need graph analysis algorithms (e.g. shortest path) there's also [pygraphlib](http://pygraphlib.sourceforge.net/doc/public/pygraphlib-module.html).

There are alternatives to graphviz, e.g. [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) / [infovis](http://thejit.org/).  Both are javascript based, provide force-directed layout, and render in the browser.

Apologies if I misunderstood question, hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the links. The problem is visible if you look at simjava, and then look for something equivalent in pydot which uses graphviz. Also look at the link to a relevant question I included in the question's EDIT. It is not obvious how to make dynamic simulations and visualize the changes 'online'/'realtime' as movements on the network...

Answer (score 1):

May be [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) (cross-platform GPL plotting library) can meet yours requirement. Graph visualization is not the main goal of MathGL. However, it have a primitives (rectangles, lines, marks, curved text and so on) which allow one to make a graph. Also it can handle data in 3D. And it allows interaction -- it return the object Id at selected position (at mouse click).

Answer (score 0):

If you want tools to actually do simulation plus viz, perhaps `netlogo`: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/  if you just want to visualize links changing in time, perhaps `Gephi`: http://gephi.github.io/  or the `ndtv` R package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ndtv/index.html